# Postgresql row policy by user and row data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table named `products` in my postgresql 9.5 database. And this table fields are like this:

- id
- name
- sales_area

And data is like this:

```
    id       name       sales_area
    1        prod1      A1
    2        prod2      A1
    3        prod3      A2
    4        prod4      A3
```

And I want to create a database user named user1, and this user should select, update and delete only `A1 sales_area` datas. Other database user will select, update and delete all datas.

Is this rule possible using policy? And How?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you can create a sample view(applying a condition where sales_area = 'A1') and grant permission to "user1" over new view.

Comment: Can user insert or delete using this view?

Comment: Yes, it should. there are some keywords and rule that should be taken care then it will allow to perform all the dml

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be done using row level security as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE products ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY for_user1 ON products AS PERMISSIVE
   FOR ALL TO PUBLIC
   USING (current_user <> 'user1' OR sales_area = 'A1');
```

Then `user1` can only access `sales_area` A1 and everybody else can access everything.

Some explanations:

- `FOR ALL` means “for all actions”, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html):

  > Using `ALL` for a policy means that it will apply to all commands, regardless of the type of command.
- The lack of a `WITH CHECK` clause does not mean that data modifications won't be checked. Again a quote from the documentation:

  > `ALL` policies will be applied to both the selection side of a query and the modification side, using the USING expression for both cases if only a `USING` expression has been defined.

Comment: Does "For all to public" contains select insert update?

Comment: I have extended the answer in the hope to cover this and other questions.

Answer (score 0):

About permission am not sure, but alternatively, you can create a view as below and give them permission to "user1" to a new view.

```
create table tx1(id int,name varchar(20),sales_area varchar(20));
insert into tx1 values(1,'prod1','A1');
insert into tx1 values(2,'prod2','A1');
insert into tx1 values(3,'prod3','A2');
insert into tx1 values(4,'prod4','A3');

create view tx1_view
as select * from tx1 where sales_area='A1';

insert into tx1_view values(5,'prod5','A1');

select * from tx1_view;
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f091a8/1)